# Handling sessions and idle timer between multiple tabs in a React SPA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm developing a React application that has *user authentication* with session duration. While login, the response will give session duration with userObject. I'm persisting the loggedUser object using **redux-persist** in localStorage. I used **react-idle-timer** to detect the tab idle with sessionDuration I'm getting in loggedUser Object. when user idle reached timeout then, I'll clear the localStorage results user logout.

#### Here is the Issue I'm facing:

The flow is working exactly for the single tab. when user uses multiple tab. For example, I'm opening a page in the second tab, loggedUser data will be shared using localStorage, here I'm actively using the page. but the first tab gets idle and when the duration exceeds the first tab will be loggedOut by clearing the localStorage, the user who uses second tab actively will be forced to logout, since there is no loggedUser data (localStorage).

How can I handle this?

Comment: Check if this helps you - https://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/

Answer (score 2):

Yeah... At the beginning I was facing the same issue. You're not alone, dear. Just add the `crossTab` property to the code and your problem will be solved.

```html
<div>
  <IdleTimer
    crossTab={true}
    ref={idleTimerRef}
    timeout={1000 * 60 * sessionTimeoutPeriod}
    onIdle={onIdle}></IdleTimer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the crossTab property in the IdleTimer component to true.

```html
<IdleTimer
  crossTab={true}
  ref={idleLogoutRef}
  timeout={timeOutLogin * 60 * 1000}
  onIdle={logoutUser}
  onActive={stayActive}
></IdleTimer>
```

Answer (score 1):

If not using a library, you can subscribe to *on change* events in local storage and refresh the page.

Example:

```
window.addEventListener( 'storage', function ( event ) {
    console.log( event.key );
    if ( event.key === 'user_logout' ) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
} );
```

The event does not fire on the tab that is making the change, but it fires on the rest of the domain's tabs in the browser.

Comment: Although this isn't the best way in this instance it's an interesting idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `isLastActiveTab` callback func of the API, so that the `onIdle` Callback will be executed only if the last active tab is going Idle:

```
//useIdleTimeout.js

const useIdleTimeout = ({promptBeforeIdle, idleTime = 1}) => {

  const idleTimeout = 1000 * idleTime;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const {isLoggedIn} = useSelector(state => state.login);

  const handleIdle = () => {
    if(isLoggedIn && idleTimer.isLastActiveTab()) {
     // Logout Logic goes here
      axios.post('/logout').then((res) => dispatch(logout())).catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
  }

  const handleTabFocus = () => {
    idleTimer.reset();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('focus', handleTabFocus);
    return() => {
      window.removeEventListener('focus', handleTabFocus);
    }
  },[]);

  const idleTimer = useIdleTimer({
    crossTab: true,
    timeout: idleTimeout,
    promptBeforeIdle: idleTimeout / 2,
    onPrompot: onIdle,
    onIdle: handleIdle,
    debounce: 500
  });

  return {
    idleTimer
  }
}

export default useIdleTimeout;
```

In the example above i have assumed that you are storing *'isLoggedIn'* variable in your redux store, to make sure that the user is logged in before performing the logout.

In your *HomePage* or *App* Component :

```
const App = () => {
 
 const handleBeforeIdle = () => {
   alert('Notify User, he is about to be Idle');
 }

 const {idleTimer} = useIdleTimeout(promptBeforeIdle: handleBeforeIdle, idleTime: 10});

return (
 // ...
)
}
```

Note that this solution resolves two issues with cross Tabs Idle timeout:
1- Prevent the *onIdle()* callback function if the user is active on at least one tab, and inactive on the others.
2- *onIdle()* will be executed only once, by the last active tab.